# Calcular idade através da data de nascimento

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou tentando calcular a idade em um campo de um formulário através da data de nascimento , só que me retorna o erro de compilação `13 type mismatch`. Por favor alguém me ajude? Eis o CODIGO.

```
Private Sub CmbCalcular_Click()

    Dim datanasc As Date, idade As Integer

    datanasc = CDate(MskDataNasc.Mask)
    idade = CInt((Date - datanasc) / 365)
    TxtIdade = Str(idade) & "anos"

End Sub
```

Comment: o problema se dá na linha onde se encontra o maskedbox.

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns erros o seu exemplo. Na linha `idade = CInt((Date - datanasc) / 365)` você está usando a classe `Date` como se fosse uma instancia.

Outra coisa é que para obter intervalos de tempo como número de dias, meses ou numero de anos use a classe `TimeSpan`([https://docs.microsoft.com/system.timespan](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2))

```
Private Sub CmbCalcular_Click()

    ' Declare a variável intervalo com sendo do tipo TimeSpan
    Dim datanasc As Date, idade As Integer, intervalo As TimeSpan

    'Use propriedade Text ao invés de Mask. 
    'Mask é mascara de edição e Text é o valor digitado  
    datanasc = CDate(MskDataNasc.Text)

    ' Compute a diferença ente hoje e datanasc 
    intervalo = Now - datanasc;

    ' use a propriedade TotalDays para obter número de dias decorridos
    idade = Math.Abs(intervalo.TotalDays  / 365)

    TxtIdade = Str(idade) & "anos"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize [`IsDate(valor)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx) que vai retornar `true` se a data for válida, utilize `Text` para pegar o valor do conteúdo [`MaskedBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms234872(v=vs.90).aspx) e por fim não `Date` é `Now` para pegar a ***data atual***, ou seja, tem três problemas no seu código:

*Solução:*

```
Private Sub CmbCalcular_Click()    
    Dim datanasc As Date, idade As Integer
    If IsDate(MskDataNasc.Text) Then
          datanasc = CDate(MskDataNasc.Text)
          idade = CInt((Now - datanasc) / 365)
          TxtIdade = Str(idade) & "anos"
    Else
          TxtIdade.Text = "Data inválida" 
    End If    
End Sub
```

O **erro** informado [type mismatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3etdkytt.aspx), significa que tentou converter para um determinado tipo, mas, essa conversão não é válida, então, utilize [`IsDate(valor)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx) antes para verificar se é possivel a conversão para `Date`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CalculaIdade(ByVal dDataNasc As Date, Optional ByVal dDataHoje As Date = Nothing) As String

    Dim cResult As String = ""

    If dDataHoje = Nothing Then
        dDataHoje = Today
    End If

    If dDataNasc <> Nothing AndAlso dDataNasc <= dDataHoje Then

        Dim dDataTemp = dDataNasc
        Dim anos = DateDiff("yyyy", dDataTemp, dDataHoje)

        dDataTemp = dDataTemp.AddYears(anos)

        Dim meses = DateDiff("m", dDataTemp, dDataHoje)
        If meses < 0 Then
            anos = anos - 1
            dDataTemp = dDataTemp.AddYears(-1)
            meses = DateDiff("m", dDataTemp, dDataHoje)
        End If

        dDataTemp = dDataTemp.AddMonths(meses)

        Dim dias = DateDiff("d", dDataTemp, dDataHoje)
        If dias < 0 Then
            meses = meses - 1
            If meses < 0 Then
                anos = anos - 1
                meses = 12 + meses
            End If
            dDataTemp = dDataTemp.AddMonths(-1)
            dias = DateDiff("d", dDataTemp, dDataHoje)
        End If

        If anos <> 0 Then
            cResult = cResult & anos & IIf(anos = 1, " ano", " anos")
        End If

        If anos < 18 Then
            If meses <> 0 Then
                cResult = cResult & IIf(cResult.Length = 0, "", ", ") & meses & IIf(meses = 1, " mes", " meses")
            End If
            If anos <= 2 Then
                If dias <> 0 Then
                    cResult = cResult & IIf(cResult.Length = 0, "", " e ") & dias & IIf(dias = 1, " dia", " dias")
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End If

    Return cResult

End Function
```